# Symfony 4 how to return invalid password instead of bad credentials on json login

Tags: symfony

So i use json login system on symfony 4 to log a user in, the default response from symfony with bad login details is 401, i didn't want that so i changed it to use a custom failure handler which returns a json response:

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;

/**
 * Class LoginFailureHandler
 * @package App\Security
 */
class LoginFailureHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param AuthenticationException $exception
     * @return Response|void
     */
    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {

        return new JsonResponse(['login'=>false,'valid'=>false,'message'=>$exception->getMessage()]);
    }
}
```

This is all fine but the exception message says "Bad credentials", what i want is to be able to return either "invalid password" or "invalid username" depending on which one was found to be invalid.

Comment: Not answering your question but bad credentials is used for security reasons since it is better to not tell (a malicious user) whether the password or username is incorrect.

Comment: Are you using guards or form authenticator ?

Comment: Following @DylanKAS comment, RGPD in europe is ruling this. 
It is not compliant with it to tell if login or password is wrong. 
Even saying "this user does not exist" is now forbidden. 
The only "ok" way to do it in longer term than "bad crendtials" is "The combination of username / password is wrong"

Comment: @ThomasL i wasn't aware of that, i understand why it is the way it is for protection against hackers knowing which one they got right, i was asked by higher powers to show it; i will go back and say GDPR says no!

Comment: @noname its not only to prevent problem against hacker. It is also to protect data privacy.
Imagine you register to a dating website to cheat on your wife. Then your wife go to that website and try you email.
Even with a wronge password, if it show "password is wrong" she knows that you are registered on it.
Well, its a funny example but it make easy to understand that way haha.
I already had a control by the french organization CNIL and they asked us to do it the way im explaining it